# HBase doesn't start with OpenJDK

Tags: hbase, java

We have installed OpenJDK 6 and JAVA_HOME is currently pointing to it. I just installed hbase-0.94.0 and we are unable to start the HBase server (start-hbase.sh) as it is looking for Sun Java. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly, paste your log details available inside your hbase folder. HBase will support open JDK 6 but it is preferable to use oracle jdk. Download Oracle JDK 1.6 and change the hbase-env.sh 
`JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jdk`  (Your Installed Java path).

Answer (score -1):

Please print the error which is coming while starting the HBase as well recheck your hbase-env.sh and check either you set right path of JAVA_HOME or not.